# How to display all datetime objects in a different timezone in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-timezone

I am relatively new to Django.

All of my datetime objects are in UTC and my **settings.py** file has `TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'`

When these `datetime` objects show up in my html template using {{ obj.datetime }}, they are dislayed in `UTC`, I want to display them in **UTC-05:00**.

How can I change this?

Note: I am using class-based views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change timezone global in your **settings.py** set:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Panama'
```

for UTC-05:00

Or you can use filter `timezone` in template - see Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#std:templatefilter-timezone)

```
{% load tz %}

{{ obj.datetime|timezone:"America/Atikokan" }}

{% timezone "America/Panama" %}
    Panama time: {{ value }}
{% endtimezone %}
```

**How can you see all available time zones?**

[pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) provides [helpers](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#helpers), including a list of current time zones and a list of all available time zones – some of which are only of historical interest.

List of timezones from wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones